# How to re-inflate the current fragment after a back returns you to the activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment with several different settings options that get checked in the onCreateView() method.  For example, There are some + and - buttons, and those could be up and down or they could be left and right.  It just changes where they're located.

This works perfectly when I'm loading the fragment, it always loads the fragment with the current settings.  However, if I leave the activity this fragment is in (MainActivity) and go to my SettingsActivity, change the options, then hit back, the MainActivity remembers which fragment was loaded (because I set launchmode to singleTop in the manifest), and it doesn't reload the fragment.

I want it to remember which fragment was loaded, but I want it to run everything that happens in onCreateView again, setting up all the buttons correctly.  Obviously I can just call onCreateView myself, but I don't know what to pass into it and I'm guessing that won't actually work because the view is being returned somewhere at the end for a reason.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Invoke the SettingsActivity from MainActivity using `startActivityForResult()`.
- Override `onActivityResult()` in MainActivity to update the UI components that are affected by the settings when SettingsActivity finishes